# Getting the 2D Screening Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I was reading the paper"Dielectric screening in two-dimensional insulators: Implications for excitonic and impurity states in graphane", DOI:10.1103/PhysRevB.84.085406, and they go from having

$$ (|\textbf{q}|^2 + k_z^2) \phi(\textbf{q},k_z) = 4 \pi e - 4 \pi \alpha |\textbf{q}|^2 \int \frac{dk_z}{2\pi} \phi(\textbf{q},k_z) $$

to this

$$ \phi_{2D}(\textbf{q}) = \frac{2 \pi e}{|\textbf{q}|(1+2\pi \alpha |\textbf{q}|)}, $$

where $ \phi_{2D}(\textbf{q}) = \int \frac{dk_z}{2\pi} \phi(\textbf{q},k_z) $.

Do you understand how they did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS does not depend on $k_z$ (it has been integrated over) so
$$
\phi({\bf q}, k_z)= \frac{1}{|{\bf q}|^2+k_z^2}(4\pi e -4\pi \alpha|{\bf q|^2} \phi_{2D})
$$
Integrate both sides wrt to $k_z$:
$$
\phi_{2D}= \left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|{\bf q}|^2+k_z^2} \frac{dk_z}{2\pi} \right\} (4\pi e -4\pi \alpha|{\bf q|^2} \phi_{2D})\\
=\frac{1}{2 |{\bf q}|}(4\pi e -4\pi \alpha|{\bf q|^2} \phi_{2D})
$$
Rearrange to get $\phi_{2D}$.

Comment: thank you so much :)